# can i get weights per iteration of MLP?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, scikit-learn, mlp

im building an mlp with scikit learn. Is there a way I can access weights and biases of the output layer per iteration? There is an option 
    `mlp.coefs_` But it outputs the train weights when the model is compiled

Comment: clf.coefs_ contains the weight matrices that constitute the model parameters:

Comment: @SachinYadav but it accessible only when the model is compiled. I want to access the weights which are updated in every iteration